# NVD3/D3 work around for series number changing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Following the guidance on adding a market to a line chart from [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/321).
I ran into an issue where if you disable a particular line that has a marker, the next line becomes a marker. I want to prevent this from happening. The series number `g.nv-series-0` of each line changes when adding or removing a particular line and that is why this occurs. Is there a work around to prevent this from happening?

In the examples below. If you click the orange "sine wave" circle on top of the plot the green line becomes dotted, and that is what I want to prevent from happening.

Here's the full example and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m8jzetx/):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.10.0/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
#chart svg {
  height: 400px;
}
#chart g.nv-scatter g.nv-series-0 path.nv-point
{
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
}
#chart g.nv-series-0 path.nv-line
{
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
data = function() {
  var sin = [],
      cos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10), shape: 'square'});
    cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
  }

  return [
    {
      values: sin,
      key: 'Sine Wave',
      color: '#ff7f0e'
    },
    {
      values: cos,
      key: 'Cosine Wave',
      color: '#2ca02c'
    }
  ];
}
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

  chart.xAxis
      .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

  chart.yAxis
      .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
      .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(data())
    .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [occurred due a bug](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1278) which has since been fixed, in the most recent version!

We can now set and access a `classed` attribute from the `css`.